# Calculating Displacement based on the compass direction

Tags: c, math, arduino-ide

I need some help with programming the calculation of displacement. Given the distance the object has moved in the XY plane, and the yaw (heading) of the object, I'd like to calculate the displacement of the object. For example, the object moved 5m North and 2m East.

The data I have is the distance it travels in the XY plane (X distance and Y distance) and the heading of the device which is determined by the direction of X. I know how to calculate it on paper but I am having trouble to program it.

I've attached two examples that shows how I obtained the calculations. The black dot is the displacement of the object. In the 1st example, the X-distance travelled is 3 meters while the Y-distance is 4 meters and the heading of the X-axis is 70°. After calculating, I managed to get that it has travelled 2.733m South and 4.187m East. In example 2, it travel, the X-distance is -5m and the Y-distance is -12m, the heading is 160°. I calculated that the object travels 8.80m North and 9.566m East.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9PyI.jpg)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGb3f.jpg)

Comment: Google 'numerical integration'

Comment: @MartinJames: this hint is irrelevant. Are you mocking the OP ?

Comment: Are you using a *left*-hand [rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule)?

Comment: @YvesDaoust no.  I made a mistake, for which I apologise to the OP.  You, however, can go to PHP for drawing malicious conclusions.

Comment: ..although, re-reading the question carefully, this seems more like a maths/geometry question than software.  Still, not sure either way, but the question is clear so I gave it an upvote anyway.

Comment: Hi, I posted the question here because I didn't know that there is an easier method to calculate the result the displacement. Since the heading might change, I thought that I had to manually calculate all the angles and vectors. Hence, I posted this question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have your XY pane rotated by some angle `Zp` and have a 2D movement vector within that pane, let's say its direction rotated by `Zv` – what is total rotation of the vector, relative to the global orientation? `Zp + Zv`...

So all you need to do is applying the rotation `Zp` to the movement vector within XY-pane, i. e. apply a rotation matrix to the vector. This matrix for a rotation by `z` looks like:

```
cos(z)  -sin(z)
sin(z)   cos(z)
```

With our data above:

```
north = cos(Zp) * x - sin(Zp) * y
east  = sin(Zp) * x + cos(Zp) * y
```

which gives, with your first sample data applied:

```
north = cos(70°) * 3 - sin(70°) * 4 ~ -2.7327
east  = sin(70°) * 3 + cos(70°) * 4 ~  4.1872

north = cos(160°) * -5 - sin(160°) * -12 ~ 8.8027
east  = sin(160°) * -5 + cos(160°) * -12 ~ 9.5662
```

Corresponding pretty much to the values you calculated (note: negative movement to north is positive movement towards south...).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. How do you get the Zp value? What terms should I look for to learn more of this?

Comment: @NoobEE Don't you have the angle available already: *'[...] heading of the X-axis is 70° [...]'*? Of course if you have the value available in degrees and want to use `sin` and `cos` functions from `math.h` you need first to calculate radiant values from, i.e. `Zp * Pi / 180`...

Comment: Why is the Zp 160° from the first example?
How do you get Zv?

Comment: @NoobEE Imagine some arbitrary vector v with an appropriate angle Zv within the XY pane. The value doesn't matter, its just for illustration. Now rotate the XY pane in thoughts – the vector rotates together with – rotation angle for the pane is Zp. Total rotation for the vector then is the sum of both angles. The important point we learn from is: We need to calculate this rotation onto the vector within XY pane to get the coordinates in the compass points pane – and this calculation I did again in Cartesian coordinates (offsets on X and Y axes), which is a simple matrix multiplication...

Comment: Note that `Zv` doesn't appear in the calculations at all any more). I took the value from your own example just to illustrate that by this algorithm you receive the same results as you did when calculating on paper.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation but why is the y-value -3 in the from the example?

Comment: You need to be able to uniquely identify the directions and together with points and vectors – either you tell 'left' or 'right' or you make one direction positive, the other one negative. I did just as for the usual Cartesian coordinate system you learnt in school: up (forward) and right positive, down(backward) and left negative – then alike for the compass points pane: north and east positive, south and west negative. This way you can apply linear algebra.

Comment: But in my example, the vector is moving right and upward. Shouldn't it be positive 3?

Can you show how to do it for example2?

Comment: @NoobEE Oh, I see, my fault... I mixed the two examples, taking values from first one while using the orientation from second one... Will be fixing.

Comment: The interesting point is that the values still match... That's due to a difference of 90° between the two angles as the following applies: `sin(x + 90°) = cos(x)`... Note, too, that I needed to swap 4 and 3 as well for having taken Y as X and -X as Y...

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help. Really had me confused just now lol.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is a conversion from polar to Cartesian coordinates. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates

If your Cartesian coordinates are not aligned to the polar axis, just compensate by adding the rotation angle to the polar argument.